# Get current sessions for Castle-Monorail site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, castle-monorail

I'm modifying a Castle-Monorail site that I've inherited and found that it would be useful to see a list of currently online users. Currently there are Filters that determine who can access which parts of the site so I can distinguish logged in sessions from non-logged in sessions. Is there an easy way of getting a list of active sessions so that I could then work out who is logged in?

Comment: do you want a list of *all* sessions, or just a list of logged in sessions?

Comment: All currently logged in sessions.

Comment: Monorail is a wrapper around ASP.NET, so if you'd take this question to a general ASP.NET forum ( or tag it ASP.NET here on SO) you are likely to get more people answering with perfectly good answers.

Comment: btw, my answer would be looking something like this:

if you're using in-proc session storage, hook into Session_Start and Session_End, and use them to control the list of currently signed in users.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've added the tag and will see if anyone answers. If not I think I'll put it to the back of the to-do list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up with:

(With help from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470571/126785 and Ken Egozi's comments)

In Global.asax.cs:

```
private static readonly object padlock = new object();
private static Dictionary<string,SessionData> sessions = new Dictionary<string,SessionData>();
public static Dictionary<string, SessionData> Sessions
{
    get { lock (padlock) { return sessions; } }
}

public struct SessionData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentLocation { get; set; }
}

protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sessions.Add(Session.SessionID, new SessionData());
}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sessions.Remove(Session.SessionID);
}

public static void SetSessionData(string sessionId, int accountId, string name, string currentLoc)
{
    Sessions.Remove(sessionId);
    Sessions.Add(sessionId, new SessionData { AccountId = accountId, CurrentLocation = currentLoc, Name = name });
}

public static void SetCurrentLocation(string sessionId, string currentLoc)
{
    SessionData currentData = Sessions[sessionId];
    Sessions.Remove(sessionId);
    Sessions.Add(sessionId, new SessionData { AccountId = currentData.AccountId, CurrentLocation = currentLoc, Name = currentData.Name });
}
```

Then when logging in:

```
Global.SetSessionData(((HttpSessionStateContainer)Session.SyncRoot).SessionID,account.Id,account.Name,"Logged In");
```

Now I just need to work out the best place to update the location from. Calls from each function could be a bit tiresome!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there isnt an easy way, unless you are storing your user logon information in the database, or an application variable, you cannot know how many active sessions there are.