# Examining all active Sessions and their contents in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, session-variables

Is there any utility that would let me examine the contents of Session objects for my website running on IIS 7/Framework 3.5 on my dev box? I've this huge code-base that stores lots of data in session state (in-proc) and I'm trying to find out what exactly is being stored. Of course I can find out the type of data by searching through the code but I was wondering if there is an external utility to do so. :)

I also looked at looping through `Session.Contents` but that gives only the current session's data while I want to examine all existing sessions.

Thanks!

Comment: I found a code-based solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470334/list-all-active-asp-net-sessions but I still leave this question open if somebody knows of some utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Sql Server mode for session state and query the tables that are used by it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on tracing on page or application level

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx

This will output all information regarding what is on your page, view state, session etc. By default information will be attached to the bottom of your page, but you can also re-direct where that trace is saved if you need to see it in QA and don't want users to see it. But normally you'd do this in development environment just to see what objects are stored.

Comment: Thanks but I want to see all sessions' data not just the current session.