# Remove user session from all the browsers that login

Tags: .net, session

If a member changes his password from a browser, all the sessions attached to that member should be removed. This is the scenario I want to handle. What I thought is to keep all sessions in a dictionary in memory like but is it efficient ? What can be the other solutions about this issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo Actually thats what I wanted. If the user change his password from computer A, how do I logout the same user from computer B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be able to get list of all active sessions just as described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/05/reading-all-users-session.aspx
when you get each session you can do with this anything you want. For example you can get used from it (you'll have to set it there when session is created see [List all active ASP.NET Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470334/list-all-active-asp-net-sessions)). 
Also you can Abandon some sessions [Session.Abandon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: And one more thing: this approach will work only if you're not using web farm or any other session distributed solutions. So as long as you have only one web server handling web requests you're fine