# Is it possible to fetch session information based on session ID in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, session

Is there a way that in a web page within the asp.net web application, show all the active sessions and the time remaining before log out? I also want to be able to manipulate these sessions (force time out, extend time out etc) from one centralised location.The session is in proc.

Or in other words, is there a class that exposes all the sessions within the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all active ASP.NET Sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470334/list-all-active-asp-net-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

Imran Baloch's gives you an excellent option in this URL:

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/05/reading-all-users-session.aspx

This is a little tricky but it does the work.

Hope it helps.