# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated use in generic asp.net handler

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, wif

I've set up an STS with WIF and want to expose whether a user is signed in so that an RP can determine if the user is signed in without requiring the user to redirect to the STS and return. If the user is signed in, a different process flow will occur on the RP so it's important to know but not to force the sign-in at this point in the process.

My plan was to create a simple generic handler on the STS which, when hit via an HttpWebRequest, returns the output of context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated (where context is the HttpContext passed into the ProcessRequest method:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    if (context.User != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        context.Response.Write("True");
    else
        context.Response.Write("False");
}
```

My problem is, if the user is signed in and I hit this handler directly, it returns True but if I programmatically hit the handler from the RP, it returns False (in fact the Identity is null).
Am I just completely wrong in doing this and hitting the handler from the RP will return the status of the User on the RP or could I be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This handler will only work (return true), if you send the STS authentication cookies with the request. Only your web browser may have these cookies. Therefore it can't be done via HttpWebRequest. Also this is why it works, when you call the handler directly from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old thread, but the answer may help others who land on this page.

The thing that does the magic behind the authentication is the session and authentication cookies which are sent to the user's client (e.g. browser) from your STS app. I'm not sure how your STS and RP apps are designed and communicate, so I will keep the answer generic. To notify your RP app of the authentication status, you need to:

1) either somehow share both cookies between the user's client and the your RP app. In this scenario, I'm afraid you will have to build your own client and make your users use it to visit the STS app. This is because you cannot get the cookies from the standard browsers. The client you build sends the cookies somewhere where your RP app can get them and place them in HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer which then can successfully get the result of your handler. I'm only explaining this method to say that it is doable and show how complex and twisted it is.

2) or you will have to track the login status of your users. Instead of checking the context.User, your handler must get the user ID from the calling RP app and then check if that user is logged in (that is there is an active session for that user). For example, you can track or store your sessions in the database, or have a look at the following thread for some methods of accessing active sessions:

[List all active ASP.NET Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470334/list-all-active-asp-net-sessions)