# How to pass windows authentication from ".aspx" page to ".ashx" handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, ntlm

I have a page "Download.aspx" which requires Windows Authentication.  When the user logs in they are presented with a list of links to files that they can download.  The links actually point to a "ZipHandler.ashx" handler which processes the requests based on the parameters passed.

My problem is that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false` inside the `ProcessRequest` method of the `IHttpHandler` when an authenticated user accesses that handler.

I need to check if they are authenticated inside the IHttpHandler because unauthenticated users can also access the handler with different results.  I've tested the value of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` inside the "Download.aspx" page and the value is `true` so I don't understand why this is not the case for the ashx handler.  I've tried adding the IReadOnlySessionState and IRequiresSessionState interfaces to my handler but I still have the same problem.

Comment: similar problem discussed in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512229/user-identity-isauthenticated-use-in-generic-asp-net-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the .ashx handler allows anonymous access but Windows Authentication will not even pass the `WindowsIdentity` along if the handler allows anonymous access.  What I did to fix this is to create 2 handler entries in the web.config that point to the same handler class:

```
<add name="AnonymousHandler" verb="GET" path="*/AnonymousHandler.ashx"
     type="MyLibrary.MyHandler, MyHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=12e530ccad45314d"/>

<add name="AuthenticatedHandler" verb="GET" path="*/AuthenticatedHandler.ashx" 
     type="MyLibrary.MyHandler, MyHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
     PublicKeyToken=12e530ccad45314d"/>
```

then I denied anonymous access to the authenticated version:

```
<location path="AuthenticatedHandler.ashx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```