# Querying session data when using StateServer service

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, stateserver, inproc

Does anybody know of a way to query across all active sessions when using StateServer service in a .NET 4.0 web app?

In my scenario, I am setting a piece of session data when the user navigates to one of our partner sites. The partner site then periodically calls a service on our site which verifies if the session is still active and returns some other data.

I managed to get it working when I was initially using InProc sessions using the solutions outlined in: [List all active ASP.NET Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470334/list-all-active-asp-net-sessions), however when I switched to using StateServer service, these techniques don't work and I can't query the sessions.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go through this article - [Counting the Currently Active Sessions](http://www.drdobbs.com/counting-the-currently-active-sessions/184416793)

> The session state is stored in a database called ASPState. The
>   database includes several stored procedures and creates a couple of
>   tables to the TempDB database. The tables are called
>   ASPStateTempApplications and ASPStateTempSessions. Knowing how many
>   sessions are currently active is as easy as running a SELECT against
>   the AspStateTempSessions table. If the session is working in
>   StateServer mode, none of these tricks will work.

Reference:
[Session State Management](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=249)
[The ASP.NET Sessions Active counter (NOT State Server) shows invalid number after installing .NET 3.5 SP!](http://davidovitz.blogspot.in/2009/03/aspnet-sessions-active-counter-not.html)
[Count Active Sessions in ASP.Net](http://web-matters.blogspot.in/2009/11/count-active-sessions-in-aspnet.html), some what same as the link you specified in the question.