# Getting a list of logged-in users in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

I'm getting started with ASP.NET Identity, but I've been unable to find a way to fetch a list of the current logged in users.
To get all users I can just user

```
new ApplicationDbContext().Users
```

where ApplicationDbContext comes with the ASP.NET Web Application template, and extends `IdentityDbContext`.

But the `IdentityUser` class does not seem to have any way to query for the logged in status.

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: I'll be impressed if this is currently implemented in ASP.NET Identity

Comment: Have you thought about capturing an event that occurs when a user logs in? Store that information in a database table or in memory. When the user logs out, remove that user from the database or memory.

Comment: I don't believe so - concept of "currently logged in" is very application specific so it is unlikely to have implementation that work for many cases.

Comment: What do you mean it's application specific? Also, about capturing the log in event. I could do it, but what about when a user is automatically logged out? I haven't seen any events related to log in or log out.

Comment: you can create custom `IHttpModule` implementation, there you can subscribe to PostAuthenticateRequest and AuthenticateRequest context events, and check there if context.Request.IsAuthenticated, this will be a good starting point.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no built in support for this.  One simple way you could implement this would be to add a LastActivityDate to your user, which is updated whenever a user does something on your site.  Then you can just query against that looking for users who are active within some reasonable time, like 30 minutes and display that.