# How can I get all logged-in users on my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need all active users logged on my website. I know I can take my logged-in user:

```
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

but how can I take all?

Comment: High level: you could use SignalR for example, or store the active users in the application object of asp.net.

Comment: @gsharp can you show us an example of how this might be achieved?

Comment: there are tons of articles out there. just google for it. for example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1080698/How-To-Show-Currently-Online-Users-Members-Using-A @CiaranGallagher

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET membership has a feature that works for FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise you need to write to a persistent store somewhere the most recent activity date & then query that table for all users active within a certain window. A web app is stateless, so "actively logged" in is a fictional abstraction we imagine over a stateless protocol. After a request is over the server has forgotten about you. [Another hack might be to count how many sessions are still alive if you are using sql session store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470334/list-all-active-asp-net-sessions).

Comment: ? The page you linked to is a method for returning all the users in the database, not the users that are logged onto the application? ("Gets a collection of all the users in the database.")

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That only gives a count of the users Matthew :( . I had a look around and there doesn't seem to be a built-in way of getting logged on users.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher IsOnline property from the results of the GetAllUsers method. The property is there, it may or may not be implemented for all providers. ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -3):

Create a field in user table named "IsLogin". 
Set IsLogin = 0 when user Signup.
Update the field whenever user logged in to the system i.e. IsLogin = 1

Now in order to get all logged-in users :
Check all records in a user table whose have IsLogin = 1
Your choice save the result in user object or just store ids or names of those users who are logged-in
Hence you store the result in array or any collection (i.e List)
Now you can easily enumerate list from start till end to get all logged-in users.

I used this method, It is the most recommended way.

Comment: I haven't marked you down, but what happens when the user closes the browser, their system crashes, they loose internet connection? I don't think this solution is very reliable.