# How to get All Login Users in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are using custom membership tables for logging of our clients.one admin person is given previlage to add users, lock them,unlock them.suppose if 2 users are logged in, then how the admin person will know 2 users are logged in and he can not lock them

Login Code ----

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            SetupFormsAuthTicket(model.UserName, model.RememberMe, model.Password);

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

For Locking Of Users

```
public void UpdateUser(User user)
{
    var usrEntry = Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);
    usrEntry.IsActive = user.IsActive;
    usrEntry.Block = user.Block;
    SaveChanges();
    var data = GetRolesDb();
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details. Like how are you login in the users (maybe the code for that) and witch version of MVC are you using

Comment: mvc version 5.2.0. Multiple users Access. Only Single User Admin. Admin Can Lock,Unlock and Block Users.

same application can be used my multiple users with different user credentials and only admin person can have privilege of locking and unlocking the users

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to login the user and the code that you use to lock the user. edit the question and post it there.

Comment: We would need to know witch kind of membership service you are using and what auth method are you using.

Comment: We are Using Form Authentication and MembershipProvider

Comment: @Naresh Build a list of online users... see http://forums.asp.net/t/1875059.aspx?How+to+get+a+list+of+all+users+currently+logged+in+with+asp+net+mvc+3 also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550014/how-can-i-get-all-logged-in-users-on-my-website