# List all active ASP.NET Core Sessions

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I list (and iterate through) all current ASP.NET Core sessions?

In pre-Core times we had the option to listen to `Session_Start` and `Session_End` events --> [List all active ASP.NET Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470334/list-all-active-asp-net-sessions)

What can we do in Core as there are not such events? I found a [workround for `Session_Start`](https://gist.github.com/FransBouma/1378210503a13e4efeb872df1f630066) but nothing for `Session_End` so far. Then again, maybe there is a completely different approach that can be used with ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

You can use database such as Redis to get all user sessions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Redis is very simple to deploy.
1.Download from https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases "Redis-x64-5.0.14.1.zip" execute "redis-server.exe" Then you host a redis server at port 6379.
[image]
2.In Asp.net Core project, install package "windows.extensions.caching.stackexchangeredis." And register service. Sessions will automatically using redis with this simple configuration.

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
{
    option.Configuration = "localhost";
});
```

3.Now you can use the following code to get all sessions in the redis server.

```
ConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379,allowAdmin=True,connectTimeout=60000");
var AllSessions = multiplexer.GetServer("localhost:6379").Keys();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", AllSessions));
```

[image]
It is same if you check sessions using redis destop manager
[image]

For Session_End there seems no samples to write a middleware.
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11869